# How to implement Specific field data into one list and Another filed data into another list in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django 3x. I have one table called Book. When I write a query for this I'm getting data like this:

```
book_details = Book.objects.all().values()
print(book_details)

<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'author': 'ABC', 'price': 150, 'category': 'Comic', 'available': 1}, {'id': 2, 'author': 'XYZ', 'price': 500, 'category': 'Historical Fiction', 'available': 1}, {'id': 3, 'author': 'MNO', 'price': 200, 'category': 'Horror', 'available': 0}]>
```

I'm trying to create data in this below format

```
{'id':[1,2,3], 'author':['ABC', 'XYZ', 'MNO'], 'price':[150,500,200], 'category':['Comic', 'Historical Fiction', 'Horror'], 'available':[1,1,0]}
```

How to create data in this format.

Please advise the best way to do this. An explanation would be much appreciated. Thanks!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do:

```
lst_of_dicts = list(book_details)
```

You will obtain the following, so if you print `lst_of_dicts`  it will look like this:

```
[{'id': 1, 'author': 'ABC', 'price': 150, 'category': 'Comic', 'available': 1},
{'id': 2, 'author': 'XYZ', 'price': 500, 'category': 'Historical Fiction', 'available': 1}, 
{'id': 3, 'author': 'MNO', 'price': 200, 'category': 'Horror', 'available': 0}]
```

So this is a list of dictionaries, while you want a dict of lists so there is a further step that you must need to do and that is this one:

```
from itertools import chain   # Necessary import

keys = set(chain(*[dic.keys() for dic in lst_of_dicts ]))
final_dict = {key : [dic[key] for dic in lst_of_dicts if key in dic] for key in keys }
```

`final_dict`  will look like this:

```
{'id': [1, 2, 3], 'author': ['ABC', 'XYZ', 'MNO'], 'available': [1, 1, 0], 'price': [150, 500, 200], 'category': ['Comic', 'Historical Fiction', 'Horror']}
```